# How to identify one router amoung multiple routers with same name?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I use windows 7. WiFi is enabled in my office. There is a static IP and a port, that we need to configure in the LAN Settings, under internet options to connect to internet. When connecting to internet, browser will ask for un/pw and we were able to connect.

We had 4 wifi routers. Months back, we were able to identify each router individually, like WC1, WC2, WC3 and WC4 under available wifi networks (on the task bar). But now, there is just a single WC instead of 4 connections and we connect to it. My device will automatically connect to the nearest router. But we can no more identify individual routers. But I want to get rid of this, Even if I am near to a router, I want to connect to another one. For this, I want to differentiate them once again. How can I do this??

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hey, I'm a little confused by your setup. So with the WC1, WC2, etc. Those names are what (SSID's, Windows Wireless names, etc.)? My understanding is that a wireless name is simply a name unless its an SSID then it has no relevance to the device its coming from, for example I could setup an ad hoc network here and name it WC1 but it would have nothing to do with your network...

Comment: there were multiple names (so that i was able to see different routers), but now, i can see a single name (still 4 routers exists)

Comment: What is the purpose of connecting to another AP? This setup is the way it should be, 1 SSID, 1 wireless network and you just move from AP to AP where the signal is best. Before, your admins probably didn't have the knowledge or equipment to set this up. In this situation, all your AP's extend the same wireless network, you use 1 configuration for all APs and it's much easier to travel from 1 location to the next without needing to reconnect.